# How to update a Spreadsheet add-on made in a default GCP project?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

I am trying to update a Spreadsheet add-on made in GCP default project, but in trouble now. Firstly, I thought I had to switch default GCP project to standard GCP project because of the following article.

> When standard GCP projects are required
> When you wish to publish your script project as an add-on in the Google Workspace Marketplace.
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#when_standard_gcp_projects_are_required

Then, I have done this one: [Switching to a different standard GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project). Now, I have the followings:

1. Google Spreadsheet which has Google Apps Script with the standard GCP project number (i.e., No.2)
2. Standard GCP project which has no listing in Google Workspace Marketplace
3. Default GCP project which has the existing add-on listing in Google Workspace Marketplace

What is the next step? I am worried if I use the standard GCP project to make a new listing, there will be two listings and current users have to uninstall and install again. Is there any way to move the listing info from the default GCP project to the standard GCP project? It would be highly appreciated if you could give me warm help.

Comment: You cannot use a default GCP project to publish an add-on as far as I know (see [Create a standard Google Cloud Platform project](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview#create_a_standard_google_cloud_platform_project)). How did you manage to do that?

Comment: I published the add-on almost three years ago. I guess that the type of GCP project was not required to publish at that time.

Comment: I don't think what you want to do is possible. The listing URL is automatically generated and based on the project number so, for a different project, it would be a different URL. Why do you want to switch the project now? You cannot update the add-on if you don't do that?

Comment: It might be my mistake. I thought I have to switch the type of GCP project because of [this article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#when_standard_gcp_projects_are_required).

Comment: Is there any way that I can still do such as reverting GCP standard to GCP default? Or, if I create a new listing with the GCP standard project, is it possible current users will automatically get the update? I mean, I can accept the listing URL is changed.

Comment: I had the same problem.  After reviewing some notes that I had made to myself about the situation, I realized that I was unable to resolve the situation myself.  I had to eventually, file an issue in the Issue Tracker.  Google was able to help me, but only after a lot of discussion, and my issue is not open to the public to view on the Issue Tracker.  If you are publishing the add-on from a Workspace account, then they *might* be willing to help you.  But I also wouldn't be surprised if they didn't help you.  And I think that it  took me 2 months to get anyone at Google to fix the problem.